# How do I type a function that works over a Discriminated Union and knows that the type of the input is the same as the type of the output?

Tags: typescript

Using TypeScript, how do I type a function that works over a [Discriminated Union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#discriminated-unions) and knows that the type of the input is the same as the type of the output?

## Example

Suppose that I have types [like those in the Handbook](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#discriminated-unions):

```js
type Shape = Square | Rectangle | Circle;
interface Square {
  kind: "square";
  size: number;
}
interface Rectangle {
  kind: "rectangle";
  width: number;
  height: number;
}
interface Circle {
  kind: "circle";
  radius: number;
}
```

I want to define a function that works over any kind of `Shape` and preserves that kind (it won’t, say, receive a `Square` and return a `Circle`), for example:

```js
function double(s) {
  switch (s.kind) {
    case "square":
      return { ...s, size: s.size * 2 };
    case "rectangle":
      return { ...s, height: s.height * 2, width: s.width * 2 };
    case "circle":
      return { ...s, radius: s.radius * 2 };
  }
}
```

In particular, I want something like the following to work:

```js
const square: Square = { kind: "square", size: 4 };
const doubleSquare: Square = double(square);
```

Here are some things that I tried and didn’t work:

## Let the Type Be `Shape`

```js
function double(s: Shape): Shape {
  // ...
}
```

The problem with this approach is that it loses the connection between input and output: as far as the type system is concerned, `double` could received a `Square` and return a `Circle`. Then the type system rightfully complains that `doubleSquare` may be any kind of `Shape`.

## Use [Generic Constraints](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html#generic-constraints)

```js
function double<T extends Shape>(s: T): T {
  // ...
}
```

Now the type system is happy about `doubleSquare`, but it doesn’t like the [Type Guards](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#type-guards-and-differentiating-types) in the `switch`, for example in

```js
case "square":
  return { ...s, size: s.size * 2 };
```

it complains about `s.size` saying that `s` still has type `T extends Shape`.

I expected this to work, particularly because `Shape` is an [Union Type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#union-types)—there are only so many kinds it may be (`Square`, `Rectangle`, or `Circle`).

## [Overload](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#overloads) the Function

```js
function double(s: Square): Square;
function double(s: Rectangle): Rectangle;
function double(s: Circle): Circle;
function double(s: Shape): Shape {
  // ...
}
```

This actually makes the type system happy, but it makes me sad. First, because I have to spell out all kinds of `Shape`. Second, because the type system won’t help me if I make a mistake in the implementation, for example, if I receive a `Square` and return a `Circle`:

```js
case "square":
  return { kind: "circle", radius: s.size * 2 };
```

## The Workaround

Currently, I’m using the type described in **Let the Type Be `Shape`** and using a [Type Assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions) to silence the type error:

```js
const square: Square = { kind: "square", size: 4 };
const doubleSquare: Square = double(square) as typeof square;
```

## Other Things I Heard About

After some research, I think that maybe what I need is a Generalized Algebraic Data Type (GADT), or a [Conditional Type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#conditional-types). But these seem to be big hammers, and I don’t even know exactly how to use them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A combination of the generic and overloaded approaches work best here. The generic signature can be the public signature, this will ensure that the type passed in is the same as the type passed out. The `function double(s: Shape): Shape` will be the implementation signature and will allow us to manipulate the parameter easier:

```
function double<T extends Shape>(s: T): T
function double(s: Shape) : Shape {
  switch (s.kind) {
    case "square":
      return { ...s, size: s.size * 2 };
    case "rectangle":
      return { ...s, height: s.height * 2, width: s.width * 2 };
    case "circle":
      return { ...s, radius: s.radius * 2 };
  }
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBAygFgQ0lAvLAjgVwQJ2gHygCUIBjYBAOwHMAbAqAYQEsdT6BuAKGcuAhwAzBKWgwsuaAG8uUKAGteAEwBcUAEQBnCXnXc5m5gC8IaypgC2AIwHcAvjz4Dho4mQo16UGXMWVVGnjkVHQQerJQAO7MSsBwZpY2OPpQcBDM1HDACda2XA68-EIi0CxsXj4KymrqpKzsYSk4CErMmJo5SfZcXIKYlOTMAPaUUEpDmFb0ADwAKlAQAB78-pqwiJAAfAAUHVCzAJRqs739gyNjE1MQu2rwSBAHUHcb0hGa0cCkcFC7AHR+JRPSpyUgITTQLQ6MIqCJyOR4YCYHCjKRQP4YzQAGighhMak0fzx0AAVFAAExQOwpUHgyFBDyhdSw+HwxHI1HozE4tIZLIEv68zLAKBk8k46KxeK4v6SuKiilUmlQMEQjR1cowuFsiBIlHeLlEnHNVrtAUmtprMVKiIOOxAA)

This will not ensure the implementation itself returns the same type as passed in, the developer it still responsible for that. I have a [workaround  in a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57266294/typescript-discriminated-union-with-generics/57267604#57267604)